# Infinite Series Value

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help find the value to the following infinite series, which should be convergent ?.

$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[%
{ax^{k} \over \left(1 + r\right)^{4k - 3}} +
{bx^{k} \over \left(1 + r\right)^{4k - 2}} +
{cx^{k} \over \left(1 + r\right)^{4k - 1}} +
{dx^{k} \over \left(1 + r\right)^{4k}}\right]
$$

where $1 < a,b,c,d$ and $0 < x,r < 1$.

Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your help !.

Comment: Is $r$ positive?

Answer (score 1):

You have :
${ax^k\over (1+r)^{4k-3}} = {a(1+r)^3 ({x\over(1+r)^4})^k}$
and similar expressions for the other terms.

Using a reulst on geometric series, you should be able to get the solution.

Comment: I'm not so sure. If $r$ is negative, it's not obvious if convergence of this series is equivalent to convergence of each of the four simpler series.

Comment: It is stated in the question that $r\gt0$ (or at least I understood so)

Comment: Oh, I see. I read that as "x > 0, and separately, r < 1".

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $|t|<1$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}t^k=\frac{t}{1-t}$$
Now let $0<t:=\frac{x}{(1+r)^4}<1$, then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{(1+r)^{4k}}=\frac{x}{(1+r)^4-x}$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{ax^k}{(1+r)^{4k-3}}+\frac{bx^k}{(1+r)^{4k-2}}+\frac{cx^k}{(1+r)^{4k-1}}+\frac{dx^k}{(1+r)^{4k}}\right)\\=
\left(a(1+r)^3+b(1+r)^2+c(1+r)+d\right)\cdot \frac{x}{(1+r)^4-x}.
$$